# Python 3 stripping a string of certain characters which are in a list

Tags: python-3.x

How would one strip a string from characters which reside in a list? Eg

```
Striplist = ["+","-","!","*"];
StripString = "A+B*!-+C";
```

Comment: You can use pipe of replace
stripStr.replace("+", '').replace('-', '').replace(.....)

Comment: Are there anymore effective ways to do this?

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve your problem so far? What output have you got (and what did you expect to get instead)? While some Stack Overflow users are very generous and may try to help you even with your question very incomplete, you'll get many more, and often better answers if you ask a better question. See [ask] for more suggestions.

Comment: @Blckknght, noted, will ask better next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `str.translate()`:

```
>>> tab = str.maketrans('', '', ''.join(["+","-","!","*"]))
>>> "A+B*!-+C".translate(tab)
'ABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are lists, so use list comprehension.

chars = [“+”, “-”, “.”]

str = “x+y=1.2”

newstr = [c for c in str if not c in chars]

Will yield “xy=12”